# CXCallObserverDelegate not working

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

Problem - I've implemented CXCallObserverDelegate and not getting call backs for call state change events.

The way i make calls -

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "some phone number"), options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

I expect getting a call back in delegate function i implemented. I've debugged and found that initialization is happening successfully while setting the delegate.

My call handling class -

```
class PhoneCallManager: NSObject, CXCallObserverDelegate {

    static let callObserver = CXCallObserver()
    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "my.ios10.call.status.queue")

    override init() {
        super.init()
        PhoneCallManager.callObserver.setDelegate(self, queue: serialQueue)
    }

    func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
         // Not getting Callback here
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you show where/how you create your instance of `PhoneCallManager`?

Comment: As i said, Initialization happening successfully. I do it in some class this way - let _ = PhoneCallManager()

Comment: That is what I suspected and why I asked. You are creating your `PhoneCallManager` but not even assigning it to a local variable, so it will be released as soon as that line executes . You either need to hold a reference in a property of an object that won’t itself be released, or perhaps you intended it to be a singleton, but that isn’t what you have done.

Comment: So u mean, making PhoneCallManager as singleton will work?

Comment: It is one approach.  You need to do something to keep the object around.

Comment: Ok. Tried this solution. Tested for instances here and there if they are still persistent. No luck so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155366/discussion-between-paulw11-and-avi).

Comment: Hello @Avi, I have the same problem. did you solve it?